# Squarespace- Wells Template - Footer / logo / hover

Tags: java, css, center, footer, squarespace

I have my website for a sneaker brand.
I'm creating a new website beside to prepare the new collection, more minimalist design etc.

I did it on Wells template (because I want a sidebare navigation)

I would like to know a few things, such as :

- Put the logo on the top center of the page instead of the top left
- Add the card on the top right of the screen
- Add a color on the text navigation when I go over it
- Add a filter color on some picture when I go over it
- Add a footer on all the pages

Comment: Your question is too general. Please, check [what topics you can ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Samuel Baruch! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry for that, I just arrived on the forum.

Comment: Also to say, I'm looking for code, I know that Wells template is not adapted to do what I want. 

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Structure and design options are set on Squarespace templates so for much of what you're asking here, you'll need your own code. For example, there's no built-in option to set a footer on the Wells template. It says so here: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545647-Wells-template#toc-footer

One thing though, for having a different color on navigation links when you hover over the word, go to the Design panel, then go to Site Styles and find the navigation design option for Navigation (Hover) Color. This might help: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545127-Wells-Site-Styles-tweaks#toc-site-wide-options